# Copy 2D Array in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a code that stored the data to a temporary array.

```
string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
string[] line = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
using (var reader2 = File.OpenText(@filename))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
    {
        string lines = reader2.ReadLine();
        var data = lines.Split(',');
        double[,] arrayTemp = new double[line.Length, 2];
        arrayTemp[i, 0] = double.Parse(data[0]);
        arrayTemp[i, 1] = double.Parse(data[1]);
    }
    Array.Copy(arrayTemp, GlobalDataClass.dDataArray, line.Length); //error the name "arrayTemp" does not exist in the current context.
}
```

Since 2d array is not resizable and I want my global array to be flexible,so I use the `Array.Copy` method to copy the temp array to the Global class array. However I got an error as commented in my code above.

My question is how to copy the `tempArray` to the global class array.
Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT:

it seems that you are trying to copy the contents of `arrayTemp` to `GlobalDataClass.dDataArray`, but you are assigning values to `GlobalDataClass.dDataArray`, and trying to copy empty `arrayTemp` to `GlobalDataClass.dDataArray`.

So first declare the `tempArray` outside the for-loop and then populate it instead of `GlobalDataClass.dDataArray` inside the for-loop accordingly:

```
string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
string[] line = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

var arrayTemp = new double[line.Length, 2];

using (var reader2 = File.OpenText(@filename))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
    {
        string lines = reader2.ReadLine();
        var data = lines.Split(',');
        arrayTemp[i, 0] = double.Parse(data[0]);
        arrayTemp[i, 1] = double.Parse(data[1]);
    }
    Array.Copy(arrayTemp, GlobalDataClass.dDataArray, line.Length); // now the error should go away.
}
```

### EDIT 2:

you don't need to read the file 2nd time in the `using()` clause.

Now please try the following:

```
string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
string[] line = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

var arrayTemp = new double[line.Length, 2];

for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    var data = line[i].Split(',');
    arrayTemp[i, 0] = double.Parse(data[0]);
    arrayTemp[i, 1] = double.Parse(data[1]);
}
Array.Copy(arrayTemp, GlobalDataClass.dDataArray, line.Length); // now the error should go away.
```

Comment: Wow,you even correct my mistakes. There's no error now, but the code resize doesn't work. It still prompt input string not in correct format whenever i load text file which have less length then my global class array..do you have any solution please?

Comment: @Ren: you need to add this line -> `GlobalDataClass.dDataArray=new double[line.Length,2];` after `arrayTemp` declaration, check my edited answer.

Comment: @Ren please follow EDIT 2 in my answer

Comment: @WasifHossain I still have the same error: " input string not in correct format"..any idea please?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi thanks. But even if I add as you said. It still prompt "input string not in correct format"..

Comment: @Ren: please provide more info like line no, and alos debug and please tell me the values where exception raises.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem :** You have declared your array variable `arrayTemp` inside the for loop and it is not available outside of it.

**Solution :** You need to move your array variable `arrayTemp` declaration outside the loop.

Try This:

```
 string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
 string[] line = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
 double arrayTemp=new double[line.Length,2];//declare outside forloop so it available after forloop.
 GlobalDataClass.dDataArray=new double[line.Length,2]; //add this line
 using (var reader2 = File.OpenText(@filename))
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
   {
     string lines = reader2.ReadLine();
     var data = lines.Split(',');         
     GlobalDataClass.dDataArray[i, 0] = double.Parse(data[0]);
     GlobalDataClass.dDataArray[i, 1] = double.Parse(data[1]);
   }
    Array.Copy(arrayTemp, GlobalDataClass.dDataArray, line.Length); 
 }
```

Comment: @Cyral: Thanks for your Kind support :)

Comment: I follow your codes, but now I have different error message at the same line. Error: use of unsigned local variable. any idea please....:(

Comment: @Ren please see my answer below. Thanks! please don't forget to accept and upvote the correct answers.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi It still prompt "input string not in correct format". Maybe it does not resize the GlobalDataClass array..correct me if im wrong...=(

Comment: @Ren: assign it to null before assigning size to `GlobalDataClass.dDataArray` as  `GlobalDataClass.dDataArray=null`;

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi already set it to null like:  static class GlobalDataClass { public static double[,] dDataArray = null; } but still did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your `tempArray` is out of the [scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) of you `Array.Copy` because it is inside of your for loop, you need to move it into the scope of your method call so the method can access it. (Similar to how `GlobalDataClass.dDataArray` is declared elsewhere)

```
//Array is now declared in an accessible scop
double[,] arrayTemp;
string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
string[] line = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
using (var reader2 = File.OpenText(@filename))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
    {
        string lines = reader2.ReadLine();
        arrayTemp = new double[line.Length, 2];
        var data = lines.Split(',');
        GlobalDataClass.dDataArray[i, 0] = double.Parse(data[0]);
        GlobalDataClass.dDataArray[i, 1] = double.Parse(data[1]);
    }
    Array.Copy(arrayTemp, GlobalDataClass.dDataArray, line.Length); //error the name "arrayTemp" does not exist in the current context.
}
```

Statements "deeper" into the { } hierarchy are only accessible to statements within them, and other child scopes in them. Parent scopes outside of the original brackets cannot access the variables.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you array is out of scope because it's declared inside the for loop and you are trying to access it outside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

I have answered on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50391063/4305317)

To copy an array to another one, just use the "Clone()" function like the following:

**This is your array list**

```
object newArray = new object [row, column];
```

**When you are creating another Array just use this code:**

```
object[,] clonedArray = (object[,]) newArray.Clone();
```

Simple! Have fun!