# cast an object to multidimensional string array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I have seen how to cast an object to a string array using the code below,

```
string[] arr = ((IEnumerable)paraArray).Cast<object>()
                             .Select(x => x.ToString())
                             .ToArray();
```

My question though is if paraArray is a object (but the data is a multidimensional array) how can I cast it to a multidimensional string array?

Comment: That code isn't casting anything as a `string` array.  It's converting each `object` in a list into a `string` and then creating a new `string` array and populating it with those values.  You seem to be under some serious misconceptions regarding what casting actually is and does.  Casting something as a `string` array would look like this: `var myArray = (string[]) myObject;`.

Comment: The data is a multidimensional array of what? Object?

Comment: yeh the paraArray is passed to the function as an object. The object though I know contains rows and columns of string and double data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't achieve this via `ToArray`. The best, IMHO, you can do is

```
  object[,] paraArray = new object[,] {
    {1, 2, 3 },
    {4, 5, 6 },
  };

  ...

  string[,] arr = new string[paraArray.GetLength(0), paraArray.GetLength(1)];

  for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); ++j)
      arr[i, j] = paraArray[i, j].ToString();
```

*2d* arrays are not very convenient when working with Linq, that's why often *jagged* arrays (array of array) are preferable:

```
  object[][] paraArray = new object[][] {
    new object[] {1, 2, 3 },
    new object[] {4, 5, 6 },
  };

  ... 

  // Working with jagged array is much easier than with 2d one 
  string[][] arr = paraArray
    .Select(line => line
       .Select(item => item.ToString())
       .ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Oh its fine for it to be a jagged array. I will give that a go. If my paraArray is being passed as an object would I able to use the GetLength method or I guess I would have to do something to paraArray first?

Comment: Object doesnt natively inherit a length method, you will have to cast it

Comment: @downrep_nation: I call `arr.GetLength(...)` on `arr` which is an *array*, not just `object`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thats fine, i was answering op's question

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using LINQ for this, you can use `Array.Copy`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16437758/993547).

```
object[,] paraArray = new object[2, 2] { { "a", "b" }, { "c", "d" } };

string[,] stringArray = new string[paraArray.GetLength(0), paraArray.GetLength(1)];

for (int i = 0; i < paraArray.GetLength(0); ++i)
{
    Array.Copy(paraArray, i * paraArray.GetLength(1), stringArray, i * stringArray.GetLength(1), paraArray.GetLength(1));
}
```