# The value of the array changes even though I did not change it

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a problem here, which is that the array (firstState and state) changes their values ​​if the current values ​​​​change. What is the solution to make the current values ​​only change

```
internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] firstState = new int[,]
            {
                {3 , 2 , 4 },
                {1 , 5 , 7 },
                {8 , 0 , 6 }
            };
            int[,] state = firstState;
            int[,] current = state;
            ArrayList values = new ArrayList();

            //left
            if (current[0,0] != 0 && current[1, 0] != 0 && current[2, 0] != 0)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                    {
                        if (state[i,j] == 0)
                        {
                            int swap = state[i, j - 1];
                            state[i, j - 1] = 0;
                            state[i, j] = swap;
                            values.Add(state);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to fix the error, but I don't know what the problem is and why the values ​​change. I did not change them

Comment: `firstState`, `state`, and `current` are all the same array.  Any changes made to that array will be visible when observing that array, regardless of which reference you use to observe it.

Comment: I.e., Array is a reference Type -- Don't spam tags, `java`, `asp.net` and `winforms` have nothing to do with the content of the question

Comment: you need to declare three different arrays if you want to change the values inside of one without effecting the others

Comment: Even if you are special please don't use `ArrayList` (which is soo 2003) - use `List<int>` instead. Please also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265542/does-array-copy-work-with-multidimensional-arrays that shows how to copy arrays (which is likely the core of the problem with this code) as well as the [MRE] guidance to make sure that code in the question is really just about the problem you have and nothing else (and includes exact details of expected/desired behavors).

Comment: How did the core issue not jump out at you when you debugged your code???

Answer (score -1):

```
internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] firstState = new int[,]
            {
                {3 , 2 , 4 },
                {1 , 5 , 7 },
                {8 , 0 , 6 }
            };
            int[,] state =   new int[]
           {
                {3 , 2 , 4 },
                {1 , 5 , 7 },
                {8 , 0 , 6 }
          };
            int[,] current = new int[]     
           {
                {3 , 2 , 4 },
                {1 , 5 , 7 },
                {8 , 0 , 6 }
           };
            ArrayList values = new ArrayList();

            //left
            if (current[0,0] != 0 && current[1, 0] != 0 && current[2, 0] != 0)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                    {
                        if (state[i,j] == 0)
                        {
                            int swap = state[i, j - 1];
                            state[i, j - 1] = 0;
                            state[i, j] = swap;
                            values.Add(state);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

your issue is that state is a reference to firstState and current is a reference to state which is nothing but a reference to firstState, so if you change current you change state if you change state you change firstState

If you want three independent Array's then you need to declare each of them. You haven't said what you are trying to do but this will solve the problem you describe.